# how to get next friday in sas

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
friday=intnx('week.5',today(),0)
```

Is this correct logic to get next Friday?

Comment: sorry. forgive me.  i want to get next friday in sas

Comment: If today is Friday what do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SAS `1` is Sunday, so you need to check for `6` instead.

```
data test;
next_friday=intnx('week.6',today(),1);
following_friday=intnx('week.6',today(),2);
format next_friday date9. following_friday date9. ;
put _all_;
run;
```

Output:
today is 1-MAY-2018

```
next_friday=04MAY2018 following_friday=11MAY2018
```

Note:
According to SAS documentation 0 should show the current week but it shows the previous week because we used week.6 in our case here but when using 1 instead the correct Friday is picked.

Comment: This of course will give a week from today if today is Friday. Also might want to clarify why you changed `0` to `1` in the third argument (correctly).

Comment: According to SAS documentation `0 ` should show the current week but it shows the previous week   because we used week.6  in our case here but when using `1` instead the correct Friday is picked.

Comment: Can you add that clarification to the answer, I meant?